# Expo MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync() crashes the app on android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I'm using expo managed flow to develop my app and I'm trying to use camera roll in order to show some images.

I'm using expo's MediaLibrary and once I grant access to the camera roll via `MediaLibrary.getPermissionsAsync()` then,  I try to call `MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync()` but my android crashes. Everything works on IOS.

Note: when I add `MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({ after: "" })` it does not crash but I've got an error where it says that "after key should be valid ID"...

Anyone knows what's the issue here?

Comment: same here i don't know why

Comment: @BoraErbasoglu What version of expo SDK you're using?

Comment: sdk39 solved this problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same inssue, I solved by doing this:

=>Run **expo upgrade** in your project directory (requires the latest version of expo-cli, you can update with npm i -g expo-cli).

They corrected in **Expo SDK 39~40**, mine was 38